# Retrieve object value using pointer in Parse for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I have a database schema which includes two tables in parse: Projects & Layouts.

One project A can have multiple layouts 1,2,3, etc.

I have created a pointer in the Layouts schema that maps to the projects data.

I am using Unity3D and given a query with the ProjectObjectID (column present in Projects) want to find out all rows correspondingly present in Layouts.

---

```
public void FetchLayoutsinProject(){

    var ProjectObjectID = "ULAueKLPmO";
    Debug.Log ("starting");
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Layouts");

    query = query.
            WhereEqualTo("ProjectObjectID", ProjectObjectID)
            ;
    query.FindAsync ().ContinueWith (t =>
                                     {
            AvailableLayouts = t.Result;


    });
}
```

This doesn't work. Can someone explain the right way to query a Parse.com pointer in Unity?